# Is it a good idea to second seal Frederick?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I have recently started a new campaign of Fire Emblem: Awakening, and I've been trying to use units that I rarely use to try and have some variety. One of these units is Frederick.

As many of you know, the amount of experience he gets from killing/wounding enemies is much less than the average unit. I have got a second seal in my inventory (I've already second sealed Donnel, so I don't need to use it on him) and I just finished chapter 8.

Would it be a good idea to use the second seal Frederick back to a cavalier or should I keep him as a great knight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the difficulty a bit. Keeping Frederick as a great knight until at least level 15 would be a good choice in general. Second sealing him at this point in the game won't make his XP gain any better, while potentially reducing his strengths.

Frederick is what the Fire Emblem community often calls a "Jaigen archetype" character; one who is very strong in early game but grows slowly. However, Awakening is fairly lenient with this, and Frederick is a viable character even on Hard.

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking that second sealing him back to a cavalier would make his experience gains bigger, but since it doesn't I will keep him as a Great Knight. Thanks for the help

Comment: Cavaliers have larger XP gains, but second sealing always has a permanent penalty on XP gain (which has a cap that also depends on difficulty). I don't remember the details exactly though. Basically it's not very productive to go through the Cavalier levels (with XP penalty), as he starts getting decent XP in the midgame anyway.